# SOLR 7.5 query with untrimmed whitespace

Tags: solr, whitespace

I am using SOLR 7.5. I want to search for a single letter by itself surrounded by spaces.  It looks like SOLR is trimming each token and my query.  EX :

```
q= text:" D "
```

This returns the following results :

> text = I need some D batteries.
>
> text = Franklin D. Roosevelt.
>
> text = Form D/L printed.

How can I format my query so only the first result shows up?
I've tried the following :

text:" D\ "

text:" D%20 "

Comment: That will depend on how your field is defined. The standard tokenizer will split on whitespace and punctuation / special characters. Do you want to include any entries starting with just `"D "` or ending with `" D"`?

Comment: @MatsLindh I just want "D" all by itself, so only the first result is returned.  So I guess anything starting with "D " would probably be ok.

Comment: @MikePone : Could you share the fieldType for your field...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want exact, simple, substring matches inside a single token, you can use the `KeywordTokenizer` and search using wildcards. The `KeywordTokenizer` keeps everything as a single token, which means `I need some D batteries.` will be indexed just as it is without any further processing.

You should then be able to query for this value by using `q=field:"* D *"`.

Comment: I had to create a new field type that used only the KeywordTokenizer and replace the existing field with a new field of that new type and reindex. After I did that, it worked just like you said.

Comment: Turns out the built in type "lowercase" had the KeywordTokenizer plus the lowercase filter, which is exactly what I wanted, so defining the field as the lowercase type gave me what I needed.

Comment: LowercaseFilter is one of the few filters that are multitermaware (i.e. they work properly when querying with wildcards as well), so that should work fine :-)